# pointing cPanel to heroku

Tags: heroku, dns, cpanel

I want to point my custom domain to heroku.
My provider uses cPanel.
I have followed the instructions here.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains
And added this to my DNS Zone Editor

> www.my-site.com.  14400   IN  CNAME   my-app.herokuapp.com

however it's been a day and my app still doesn't point to heroku.
It might be because there are several other records in the DNS

currently these are the records in my DNS.
I'm wondering what's wrong with my setup.
Do I have to remove the A record pointing to the IP address of the old server?
note: XX.XX.XX.XX = Old IP address

> NAME----------------------------TTL-----------CLASS------TYPE--------RECORD
>   my-site.com.---------------------14400-----------IN------------A----------XX.XX.XX.XX 
>   localhost.my-site.com.---------14400-----------IN------------A------------127.0.0.1   
>   mail.my-site.com.---------------14400-----------IN-----------CNAME-----my-site.com    
>   www.my-site.com.--------------14400   ------ ----IN---------- CNAME-----my-app.herokuapp.com  
>   ftp.my-site.com.----------------  14400------------IN----------CNAME-----my-site.com  
>   webdisk.my-site.com.----------14400-----------    IN----------A-------------XX.XX.XX.XX   
>   autodiscover.my-site.com.---  14400------------IN----------A-------------XX.XX.XX.XX  
>   autoconfig.my-site.com.------14400------------    IN----------A-------------XX.XX.XX.XX

FIX: I fixed the problem by removing the A record pointing to the old server. Then it now points to my herokuapp. I tried to put the old A record back on and it still works now (don't know why) maybe it's a conflict on the provider's side